# How do I install Windows XP via a USB - SATA/IDE adapter?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, installation, sata, adapter

I have an Asus EB1007 EeeBox that doesn't have a CD drive. I removed the hard drive and connected it to my laptop and formatted it, via a USB to SATA/IDE adapter.

How can I install Windows XP using this adapter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Windows *on* the EeeBox.

The easiest and fastest method, given Windows XP, would be to use [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) to get the WinXP setup on a USB disk/key.  Then you should be able to boot the EeeBox from the USB disk/key and install Windows from there.

Alternatively, you could get an external CD/DVD drive and use your adapter with it, but it's much faster and less expensive to go with a USB key.

Answer (score -1):

Put the hard disk back in the Eee Box, then use the USB-to-IDE/SATA adapter to connect a CD drive to it. You may need to poke at the BIOS options to get it to boot from what will be treated as a USB CD/DVD drive, but you should be good to go from there.

Comment: Windows does not support being installed on devices connect by USB.  There are tools that allow this but you didn't mention those tools.

Comment: Neither did you, I note. I also note that I'm not suggesting installing to a USB-connected hard disk, but rather from a USB-connected CD drive, on a system which (IIRC) supports booting from such a drive. I've had no trouble installing Windows this way in the past.

Comment: I don't suggest tools I have not used myself.  The author wants to install the operating system on his external USB connected internal SATA HDD.